# HTML Scraping XPath

Tags: python, html, xpath, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to scrape some data from a webpage... I managed to extract the name and the prices but I have a problem here... Photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhjE8.jpg

I wanna print all the `<li></li>` section but the numbers covered by `<bold></bold>` do not show up, why is this? I'm sure there is some way to print the whole thing.

I've been doing this: The original XPath is

```
//*[@id="ad-54132"]/div[2]/ul/li
```

Which I shortened (so that it prints all the ads no matter what number they are instead of just printing the "54132" ad) to:

```
squarefeet = tree.xpath('//*/div[2]/ul/li/text()')
```

And like i said in the beginning, it just prints the text that is not on `<bold></bold>`

Answer (score 1):

By using `li/text()` you'll only get text nodes that is *direct child* of `li`.

To get all text nodes within `li`, no matter direct child or nested, you can use `li//text()`. But that will result in multiple text nodes for each `li` which you might don't want.

If you want to get all text nodes concatenated into single text for each `li`, you can call XPath `string()` or `normalize-space()` function for every `li` element like so :

```
squarefeet = [li.xpath('normalize-space(.)') for li in tree.xpath('//*/div[2]/ul/li')]
```

`normalize-space()` behaves just like `string()` in this case, plus it removes leading and trailing spaces if any, and it also replaces sequences of whitespace by a single whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath will work:

```
//*[@id="ad-54132"]/div[2]/ul/li/*
```

The * at the end selects all the child nodes of the "**li**" tag